# Is there a Pathfinder equivalent to the Ring of Arming?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, magic-items

I wasn't able to find anything, so I was wondering: is there a Pathfinder equivalent to the Ring of Arming from D&D 3.5e, and if so, what book is it from?

I don't care if it's not a ring — I'm looking for any item with an equivalent effect in Pathfinder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides simply using the Ring of Arming as is...

There is the [Armiger's Panoply](http://archivesofnethys.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Armiger's%20Panoply) and [Folding Plate](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/specific-magic-armor/folding-plate). You could always use some GM fiat in order to customize for a different/specific set of armor and/or weapon. For weapons specifically, the [Called](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/called) special ability would be quite nice. For more of vulgar display of power, there is the [Swift Girding](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/swift-girding) spell.